# question about DE of all circles in the plane.

Tags: support

There was a review question about DE of all circles in the plane.

I wish to re-visit and moderate my own remarks somewhat to serve politeness made after Phanindra's comment (that I hold correct) and the others but I cannot access it anymore.

There I obtained

$$ y^{'''}= \frac{3 y^{'}y^{''2}}{(1 + y^{'2})} $$

but  it had to be cramped into the question itself.This was about 30 minutes earlier.

Wish to re-visit it; Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention: "there was a review question":  Was it a question posted, and were you reviewing it in the review queue, and commented?  If so, in what review queue did you encounter the question?  Or by "review question" do you mean some asker asked what they described as a review question, and you would like to update a comment or two that you left?  Need I say, what you've written is far to cryptic and hard to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was in the mood to put on my sleuth cap today:

I presume you want to revisit this question: [Equation representing all circles in xy plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600861/euation-representing-all-circles-in-xy-plane).

To find it, I went to your MSE profile, clicked on the "activity" tab, clicked on the "all actions tab", then clicked on the "comments" tab.  This brought me immediately to the most recent comment you made, along with a link to the question on which you commented.

(Might be a good idea to get to know what you can find via your own profile/activity.)